# What does "it would have been then" mean?

Tags: meaning

> If ever Harry might have released his wand from shock, **it would have been then**, but instinct kept him clutching his wand tightly, so that the thread of golden light remained unbroken, even though the thick gray ghost of Cedric Diggory (was it a ghost? it looked so solid) emerged in its entirety from the end of Voldemort’s wand, as though it were squeezing itself out of a very narrow tunnel . . . and this shade of Cedric stood up, and looked up and down the golden thread of light, and spoke.

I know the author is trying to say he would have been dead. but does "then" has a certain depressive meaning to represent those things in these kind of situations?

Comment: **then** here refers to a particular time in the past. If Harry ever did it, it would have been at that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes 'then' here refers to that particular time in the past. It is like the usage of **then** in "now versus then". (For example: If you had to turn the car aside when the deer was in front of us it would have been *then*. (But you didn't I know that)).

Then when past is also used in situations like: "Valintine's day **then** (i.e. when we were kids) and now".

Answer (score 1):

The author is **not** trying to say that Harry would have been dead. That is, the sentence does not mean:

> If Harry released his wand from shock, it would have been finished then [he would die at that time].

Instead, it means:

> Harry did not release his wand at any time, but if he had, the most likely time would have been then [at that time, because that's when the most shocking thing happened].